# Inequality between Cauchy-Schwarz-like quotients

Tags: analysis, induction, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, monotone-functions

Considering $0 < x <1$ and $0 < y < 1$, I want to prove that the following expression defined by the quotient

$$
\frac{(1-x^n y^n)^2}{(1-x^{2n})(1-y^{2n})}
$$

is decreasing in $n$.

Or, equivalently, that the following expression is decreasing in $n$

$$
\frac{\left( \sum_{i=1}^n x^i y^i \right)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n x^{2i} \sum_{i=1}^{n} y^{2i}}.
$$

I get nothing by studying the sign of the first derivative.